# How To Execute GenericHandler Method in C# WebService

Tags: c#, mysql, ajax, web-services

I have to upload images to MySQL database, im using html, ajax, javascript and c#. I have 2 codes, 1 to upload the path of the image and the other upload the image in blop field, both work fine, but im using WebService and for the file upload Im using GenericHandler, my question is, How can I execute my methods but in my WebService?

Code of the GenericHandler:

```
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
{
    string sql = "";
    string ruta = "";
    int files = 0;
    //IF para comprobar que el total de archivos cargados sea mayor a 0
    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        //Variable que almacenara todos los archivos a cargar
        HttpFileCollection SelectedFiles = context.Request.Files;
        //Ciclor for para recorrer el arreglo y darle un indice a todos los archivos
        for (int i = 0; i < SelectedFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            // Variable que tomara el valor dado por el for
            HttpPostedFile PostedFile = SelectedFiles[i];
            //Variable que tomar el valor de la ruta y el nombre del archivo que se guardara
            string FileName = context.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + PostedFile.FileName);
            // Metodo para guardar el archivo
            files++;
            PostedFile.SaveAs(FileName);
            ruta = FileName;
            if (files == SelectedFiles.Count)
                sql += ruta;
            else
                sql += ruta + '|';

        }
        FileUpload fu = new FileUpload(sql);
        conn.Foto(fu, 1);//hjjiijj.mnbfgytrvgfdhghhygd

    }
    // Else para mandar mensaje de error.
    else
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Please Select Files");
    }

    //Mensaje al realizar el metodo satisfactoriamente
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("Files Uploaded Successfully!!");
}
```

Comment: Your question sounds as if the title is not the right title. Getting a web service to work is a different problem than saving an image in MySQL.

Comment: I think that the title its better now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax, and in the url you call your generichandler.